# Salesforce Private Message REST API always sending message to ORG Admin Id

Tags: apex, community

I am trying to implement Chatter Private Message functionality in a Community Site.
For this I am using resource " ../chatter/users/me/messages/.." .
I want to send the message to a particular user ID but whats happening is ,its always sending the message & mail to org Admin's chatter feed and email Id.

Please suggest some idea so that I can implement the standard behavior of sending private message to a particular user ID from the logged-in user ID.

My End URL:- SERVER_URL+'/services/data/v29.0/connect/communities/'+communityId+'/chatter/users/me/messages?recipients=recipientID&text=Are we ready for next week customer meeting'

Using Site:- http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/chatterapi/Content/connect_resources_how_to.htm#cc_send_message

Thanks 
Arabinda